# How to optimize convertion a list of one object type to another?

Tags: java

In this example I convert objects, but have to repeat the same part of the code over and over again.
I am talking about

```
dish.getRestaurant()
```

I would appreciate if you could tell, how this can be optimized.

```
public List<DishDto> getAll() {
    List<Dish> dishlsit = dishRepository.findAll();
    return dishlsit.stream()
            .map(dish -> new DishDto(dish.getName(), dish.getPrice(),
                    dish.getRestaurant().getName(), dish.getRestaurant().getAddress(),
                    dish.getRestaurant().getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: What is not optimal about this code?  When you say "optimize," what metric are you looking at?

Comment: When you have code that you have to repeat, obvious solution is to put it in a method. Where to place such method is a mater of personal preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wish to repeat `dish.getRestaurant()`, either add a constructor to `DishDto` that takes a `Dish` as a parameter, one that takes the dish name, the dish price, and an object of type `Restaurant`, or add methods to `Dish` that return the `Restaurant` properties, like so:

```
public String getRestaurantName() {
    return this.getRestaurant().getName();
}
```

Then the code in your question becomes:

```
public List<DishDto> getAll() {
    List<Dish> dishlsit = dishRepository.findAll();
    return dishlsit.stream()
            .map(dish -> new DishDto(dish.getName(), dish.getPrice(),
                    dish.getRestaurantName(), dish.getRestaurantAddress(),
                    dish.getRestaurantId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```